# Python - writing dbf to txt, text file incomplete

Tags: python, arcgis

I am writing a script in Python to automate a GIS process. The general process is as follows:

- set up initial parameters
- establish a database connection
- run an ArcGIS model
- convert the resulting table into `.dbf`
- convert the `.dbf` to a `.txt` file
- reformat the content in the `.txt` file
- and finally add headers to the `.txt` file.

For the most part, the process works very well. The problem I am encountering is that the `.txt` file is incomplete. The resulting `.dbf` from the ArcGIS model has 7304 records, but the `.txt` file only has 7232 records. It is almost as if when writing the `.txt` file, the script just gives up before reaching the end. I cannot seem to figure out what is causing this to happen.

I will attach a portion of the script as well as the `.txt` file output. Any help/suggestions would be very much appreciated.

```
DBF = r'Q:\GIS_Mapping\BillingDept\ERU\DO_NOT_TOUCH\ReportOutput\ERU.dbf'
output_directory = r'Q:\GIS_Mapping\BillingDept\ERU\DO_NOT_TOUCH\ERU_Output'
ERU_file = os.path.join(output_directory,'ERU.txt')
arcpy.AddMessage('Creating ERU file')
print "3"
report = open(ERU_file, "w")
cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(DBF)
for row in cursor: 
    ACCT = row.getValue('ACCT')
    STR_ACCT = str(ACCT)
    NEW_ACCT = STR_ACCT.replace('.0','')
    IMPAREA = row.getValue('IMPAREA')
    STR_IMPAREA = str(IMPAREA)
    NEW_IMPAREA = STR_IMPAREA.replace(".0",".00")
    SWCODE = row.getValue('SWCODE')
    STR_SWCODE = str(SWCODE)

    report.write(NEW_ACCT + "," + NEW_IMPAREA + "," + STR_SWCODE + '\n')

del (ERU_file)
print "4"
arcpy.AddMessage('Adding headers')

headers = ['"ACCT","IMPAREA","SWCODE"']
filename = r"Q:\GIS_Mapping\BillingDept\ERU\DO_NOT_TOUCH\ERU_Output\ERU.txt"
tmp = open('TMP', 'w')
orig = open(filename, 'r')
tmp.write('\t'.join(headers) + '\n')
for line in orig.readlines():
    tmp.write(line)
orig.close()
tmp.close()
arcpy.AddMessage('Headers added, renaming file')
os.remove(r'Q:\GIS_Mapping\BillingDept\ERU\DO_NOT_TOUCH\ERU_Final\ERU.txt')
os.rename('TMP', r'Q:\GIS_Mapping\BillingDept\ERU\DO_NOT_TOUCH\ERU_Final\ERU.txt')
print "5"

os.startfile(r'Q:\GIS_Mapping\BillingDept\ERU\DO_NOT_TOUCH\ERU_Final\ERU.txt')
arcpy.AddMessage('Done')
```

Below is a portion of the `.txt` output without the headers. As you can see, the process is running fine, and then just stops after `222415613,0.00`.

```
600414006,0.00,1
602311015,0.00,1
910010858,0.00,1
2000716007,0.00,1
220735804,0.00,1
910010076,0.00,1
300724505,0.00,1
910012468,0.00,1
303737006,0.00,1
503143201,10079.33,2
213001881,0.00,1
2007212003,0.00,1
4080010042,0.00,1
4030010111,0.00,1
4090020013,0.00,1
910011618,0.00,1
221624400,0.00,1
600934006,0.00,1
505531404,0.00,1
215232207,0.00,1
600432514,0.00,1
600432011,0.00,0
404834003,0.00,1
222415613,0.00
```

Attached is a screenshot of the `.dbf`. As you can see after the `222415613` record the information continues on as normal for about another 50 or so records.

[Screenshot of .dbf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aK8nI.png)

Comment: Have You tried moving Your cursor to that specific problematic `row` instead  of iterating through whole data-set? have You tried tracing the process?

Comment: I need to iterate through the whole dataset because each time I run the ArcGIS model, the dbf will change. That number where the script is getting held up on may not even exist when this process has to be run next month.

Comment: I think what @Kamiccolo was saying is that you should copy the dbf file, if fetching the data might change it, remove all the lines before the line that fails, and run your code on that file.  See if it fails on the same record.  If so, there is something strange about the record, and not its place in the file

Comment: @joel goldstick I see what you mean. I tried this and got some interesting results. When I run the script using a dbf that only has the records from after where the script failed, the resulting txt file is blank except for the headers. When I run the script on a dbf with only the records from above where the script fails, I encounter the same problem as my original issue (i.e. most of the records turn up, but then it fails at a seemingly random spot).

Comment: The reason you're seeing random amounts of missing data is because the write buffer length varies based on other stuff your system is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `del (ERU_file)` to `report.close()`. `del (ERU_file)` just deletes the string identifying the location of the file, it doesn't actually close the open file handle and flush the data to disk.

Or better yet, use a [`with` statement](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/with-statement-in-python):

Change

`report = open(ERU_file, 'w')`

to

`with open(ERU_file, 'w') as report:`

and add a level of indent to your `cursor` declaration and `for` loop.

What's happening is that you're opening a second copy of the file, with `orig = open(filename, 'r')`, while the first copy, `report`, is still open with data still in the write buffer and not flushed to disk. When the script finishes running, that data is flushed to disk as part of python's cleanup, which is why you do see it in the file when you look, yourself.

Comment: this makes perfect sense, and appears to be the problem. Thank you for your help!